# Forms generation with CivicRM Profiles under Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, profile

When trying to use a profile for form input on a page, one of my profiles is available but the others are not.  Any ideas on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're wanting to do is possible, see a solution here, which is to create one new profile with all the fields: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32718.0

That said - CiviCRM 4.6 with Wordpress has the ability to render multiple profiles, but I'm still not sure if you can have multiple profile forms: https://civicrm.org/blogs/haystack/working-civicrm-46-wordpress